# What are the best practices for JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

I have done Java and JSP programming in the past, but I am new to Java Server Faces and want to know if there's a set of best practices for JSF development.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some tips:
Understand the JSF request [lifecycle](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=470) and where your various pieces of code fit in it. Especially find out why your model values will not be updated if there are validation errors.

Choose a tag library and then stick with it. Take your time to determine your needs and prototype different libraries. Mixing different taglibs may cause severe harm to your mental health.

Answer (score 12):

Consider using [facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/)- it greatly simplifies the worst parts of JSF development. I'm doing a CMS-based JSF project now without facelets (after doing a project with it) and it feels like my left arm is missing....

Comment: +1 on that. JSF without Facelets just feels broken.

Answer (score 12):

I would strongly recommend getting someone experienced in JSF to lead your first project in JSF even if this means paying a contractor for 3 months.
The JSF approach is very different to JSP. The way you approach and solve problems is very different.

### Libraries

Consider the following libraries:

- [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/index.html)
- [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/jbossrichfaces/)
- [Shale](http://shale.apache.org/)
- [Trinidad](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/index.html)
- [Spring](http://spring.io/)

### Architecture

Embrace [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) you need not only to know what this means but use it extensively.

There are two main patterns for associating controllers with the views

#### Dot Net Style, One Request controller per view

Every top level page has a request scoped controller (bean) all validation and actions of the page use this class. Also used for filtering and ordering the Model.
The Model will be stored on a few session level controllers which will handle talking to the back-end (EJBs, or persistence layer) these session controllers should be implementing the business logic and have no knowledge of JSF,HTML or any presentation technology.

#### Controllers are session level

Design controllers based on your data model, nest them with in each other. (This post is getting too long so I wont go into the nuts and bolts of these).

### Knowledge Required

Everyone:

- [Life Cycle](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html)
- MDC
- Component based development
- Tags in [h: and f:](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/tlddocs/overview-summary.html)

At Least One Person:

- [Creating Custom Components](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/jsf-component-writing-check-list/)
- Limitations to JSF (back button,
  random navigation, etc)
- Debug 3rd
  party libraries (At least one person
  has to be comfortable breaking out
  the debugger and stepping into the
  implementation of JSF (easiest with
  open source implementations like
  MyFaces))

Answer (score 1):

- Add my vote for facelets. I've recently upgraded a project to use facelets, and it solves some big issues with jsf, specially giving you a decent template system right out of the box and letting you use standard html when it is appropriate, without wrapping it in "verbatim"-tags.
- RestFaces is a solution to the get/post problem that many people complain about. It's also well documented and easy to use.
- Don't use to many taglibs. It makes the job a lot harder when upgrading.
- SEAM collects many of the JSF best practices, but I haven't used it yet, so I can't really recommend it, just recommend you to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the IBM implementation of JSf and have some comments. It is not a bad way to go but you have to commit to the IBM 'way-of-life'. They have written their own tag lib which extends the JSF standard. If you can manage to stay inside of Rational Application Developer (RAD) (which does not get updated THAT often), the integration is sometimes buggy but overall decent. Also the integration with WebSphere is pretty good. Unless your employer plays golf with IBM, I think it is better to stay as vanilla as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet aware of a "Best Practice" for cross field / form level validation.

That is, JSF validation is currently orientated to single field validation. IMO it gets ugly when you look at complex cross field / form level validation.

Old but still looks acurate to me
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnreynolds/archive/2004/07/improve_jsf_by_1.html

http://www.jroller.com/robwilliams/entry/jsf_multi_field_validation_not

Answer (score 0):

You could check it the following link in where you could find interesting articles

http://www.jsftutorials.net/

Answer (score -1):

Select a good component library .Do not use richfaces ,  i suggest you dont use jsf , use spring mvc,jquery fro view  and  json in a  rest architecture.  but if you have to ,use primefaces it easy to use and has enough components.